# Why is the # convention used in empty anchor tag hrefs?

Tags: html

I understand that it's a good idea not to leave empty anchor tags. In jQuery and other syntaxes I've noticed everyone typically uses a # to fill the gap (`<a href='#'>anchor text</a>`). Is this character any better or worse than filling it with anything else? (e.g. `<a href='$'>anchor text</a>`). I have no reason to want to do this, but seemingly no reason aside from convention to do it the other way either. Why is the `#` convention used in empty anchor tag hrefs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because the `#` character in a URL references the local page.

It is used for named anchors (or any ID) within a page, so a link can jump directly to that area.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) calls it the `fragment identifier` and has this to say:

> The fragment identifier, if present, specifies a part or a position within the overall resource or document. When used with HTTP, it usually specifies a section or location within the page, and the browser may scroll to display that part of the page.

---

As a practical example - this link to wikipedia has a fragment identifier (always at the end of the URL):

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax
```

In the page, there is a `<span id="Syntax" ...` tag, and the browser jumps directly to it.

Answer (score 16):

This way, if the user has disabled javascript, actually following the link to "http://mysite.com/#" will not have any negative consequences.

For example, these links still work, since `#` specifies a location on the current page:

- http://www.stackoverflow.com#
- http://www.stackoverflow.com/#

while these don't:

- [http://www.stackoverflow.com$](http://www.stackoverflow.com%24)
- [http://www.stackoverflow.com/$](http://www.stackoverflow.com/%24)

Comment: Note that if you use an anchor like `#!` or something similar, you won't have the nasty side-effect of scrolling to the top of the page if JavaScript is disabled (or if there's an error in the event listener and it fails to return `false` or call `preventDefault`).

Comment: I never knew about `#!`. Can you explain why this helps not scrolling to the top?

Comment: @Catfish Likely because `#!` refers to an anchor with ID `!` which doesn't exist. A value of `#does-not-exist` doesn't scroll up either as long as there is no element setting this ID. The benefit of `!` is that the likelihood of this fragment identifier being present is pretty low. It is a legal character for IDs, however.

Answer (score 3):

The link denoted by `<a href=` points to somewhere else. This somewhere could be on the other side of the world (absolute URL), or locally on the same domain/path (relative URL). Just leaving it empty refers to the very document itself.

The # is the character used to separate an anchor from the rest of the URL. Browers don't even send it to the server, but use it to vertically scroll to the position in the page marked with this anchor (using `<a name="foo"></a>`).

So basically, `<a href="#">` instructs the browser to stay on the same page. It is usually used together with JavaScript - hooking into onClick events - so that the JavaScript does something useful, then `return false` to prevent the browser from actually following the link. But if he would (e.g. if JavaScript is disabled, or `return false` is ommitted) then it would not leave the current site, usually not even reloading it.

So `#`is used not as a random char, but because that's actually the char specified for the purpose of denoting an anchor in a link - it just happens that in your case you neither need the actual link (to another page) nor the anchor, but just a clickable element.

Answer (score 1):

it's mostly old school way of preventing the click action to trigger a page reload.

If you aren t using the href attribute just leave it empty, or even better if you can target some fallback URL for people with JS disabled

Comment: If you leave it empty, you need to add something like `a {cursor: pointer;}` to your CSS to make it behave the same way. Besides, `href` is a required HTML attribute iirc.

Comment: if the attribute is there but just empty (as i said in my reply) it validates just fine and shows the cursor.