# html correctness link blank or pound sign

Tags: html

What's more correct, an empty string link or a pound?
For example for anchor tags 
Or if I were to reference a style sheet, basically anywhere in the html document where a link should be, if I want to remove all these links is it better to make it a pound or blank?
If you need more details i'm basically canning them and need to remove all external dependencies.

Comment: A blank will reference the current document, it's not identical with using a `#`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478811/why-is-the-convention-used-in-empty-anchor-tag-hrefs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>` to avoid any loading or scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If an anchor tag has a blank href, clicking it would cause the page to reload, whereas a pound would stay on the page, but bring them back to the top. Neither are ideal since the user would be confused...

For removing stylesheets...why not remove the whole line altogether?